# Method referring to a pulled in packaged's method moves out of scope when put inside an objects method

Tags: ruby, class, variables, methods, scope

When I put a method that refers to a pulled in package inside another method it leaves scope and fails.

What is the proper way to do this. I tried playing with the 'self' but am new and that did not work out.

Desired solution. Does not work. Returns error.

> undefined method `accounts' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
require 'package that has 'accounts''


class Name

    @sandbox = #working API connection

    def get_account
        @sandbox.accounts do |resp|         #This is where error is
          resp.each do |account|

            if account.name == "John"
                name = account.name
            end

          end
        end
    end


end


new = Name.new
p new.get_account
```

---

This works but does not create a reusable method.

```
require 'package that has 'accounts''

class Name

    @sandbox = #working API connection


        @sandbox.accounts do |resp|       
          resp.each do |account|    
            if account.name == "John"
                p account.name
            end
          end
        end




end


new = Name.new
```

Comment: You need `self.class.instance_variable_get(:@sandbox).accounts..`. That is, you need the value of the *class instance variable* `@sandbox`, so you first have to change the scope to the class: `self.class`. (This is one of the cases where `self.` is required, because without it Ruby would think `class` is a keyword.) Then, since the class has no getter for `@sandbox` you need to use the method [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).

Comment: worlds most complicated $this->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The mistake in the code is that @sandbox is an attribute of the class. The value would be initialized when an object of the class is created. Writing the initialization in the class will have no effect. @Maxim has explained this in his answer.
2. For the second code, when the interpreter runs through the code, it would execute it once. But that code cannot run more than once.

The code should be,

```
require 'package that has 'accounts''


class Name

    def initialize
      @sandbox = #working API connection
    end

    def get_account
        @sandbox.accounts do |resp|         #This is where error is
          resp.each do |account|

            if account.name == "John"
                name = account.name
            end

          end
        end
    end


end


new = Name.new
p new.get_account
```

Comment: The value of `@sandbox` is the same for all instances, so doesn`t it make sense for it to be a class instance variable?

Comment: Sure! If the @sandbox scope is class level than @@sandbox should do the trick in the code. I am unsure about the design intent in this case. With class variables, there could be some extendability issues later on if they decide to change the API for specific classes.

Comment: I'm suggesting that `@sandbox` be a class instance variable, not a class variable. (btw, many Rubiests, myself included, never use class variables.)

Comment: Oh, sorry I got confused. I also added @sandbox as an instance variable only. I misread the comment and thought the suggestion was to have it as a class variable. I think we might be on the same page here. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, you need to understand the concept of singleton classes in Ruby.

The class Name is an object itself, and `@sandbox` is an instance variable of that object.

If you write `def self.get_account` you could use `@sandox` there, but then this method is not available for instances of Name, e.g. you should call `Name.get_account` and not `Name.new.get_account`. Actually, this adds a method to the singleton class of Name, and that's why you can access @sandbox there.

To create an instance variable that could be used in the instances of `Name`, you should do so in the `initialize` method of `Name`.